# Laravel, sum in foreach

Tags: php, laravel

```html
foreach($group as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key. " = " .$value. "<br>";
}
```

for example

```
For example:

doc1 = 8

doc2 = 7

doc3 = 1

doc4 = 5
```

i want to show and sum doc1 + doc2 as TOTAL1,

then sum TOTAL1  + doc3 as TOTAL2,

then sum TOTAL2 + doc4 as TOTAL3

how to show it in blade? thank u for help me

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$group = [
    'doc1' => 8,
    'doc2' => 7,
    'doc3' => 1,
    'doc4' => 5
];

$totals = [];
$total = array_shift($group);
foreach(array_values($group) as $index => $value)
{
    $total += $value;
    $totals['total' . ($index + 1)] = $total;
};
dd($totals);
```

result is

```
array:3 [▼
  "total1" => 15
  "total2" => 16
  "total3" => 21
]
```